# Best way to make Jersey 2.x refuse requests with incorrect Content-Length?

Tags: java, rest, filter, jersey-2.0, content-length

I need to make Jersey refuse requests with incorrect content-length. I'm checking the content-length with a `ContainerRequestFilter` filter, like so:

```
public class ContentLengthRequiredRequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    private static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ContentLengthRequiredRequestFilter.class);


    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {

        if (requestContext.getMethod() == javax.ws.rs.HttpMethod.POST
                || requestContext.getMethod() == javax.ws.rs.HttpMethod.PUT) {
            int givenContentLength = requestContext.getLength();

            if (givenContentLength == -1) {
                // no content-length given, but it is is required for PUT and POST requests
        requestContext.abortWith(Response.status(Response.Status.LENGTH_REQUIRED).entity("No content-length provided.").build());

            } else {
                // now check if the given content-length is actually correct.
                // since I only have a reference to an entity stream, it seems to be that
                // reading the entire stream and then resetting it is not a good solution.

                // Should I be checking this somewhere else, perhaps somewhere the entity is already available or where I can get the total size of the body without causing the stream to be read twice? Or is there a better way to get the body size here?

            }

        }

    }
}
```

As you can see in the code block comment, should I be checking this somewhere else, perhaps somewhere the entity is already available or where I can get the total size of the body without causing the stream to be read twice? Or is there a better way to get the body size there?

Thank you!!

Comment: I think this depends very much on your payload. If your payload is also containing a filename for example your content-length is different. I would check this in the resource class typically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to buffer the incoming entity (input stream) I'd take a look at [ReaderInterceptor](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/javax/ws/rs/ext/ReaderInterceptor.html) interface. Instances of this contract are invoked only in cases when incoming requests contain an entity (typically POST, PUT). In the interceptor you can pretty much do anything with entity. A simple snippet (not covering all cases) could look like:

```
public class MyInterceptor implements ReaderInterceptor {

    @Override
    public Object aroundReadFrom(final ReaderInterceptorContext context) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        final InputStream old = context.getInputStream();
        final String first = context.getHeaders().getFirst("Content-Length");
        final Long declared = first == null ? -1 : Long.valueOf(first);

        context.setInputStream(new InputStream() {

            private long length = 0;
            private int mark = 0;

            @Override
            public int read() throws IOException {
                final int read = old.read();
                readAndCheck(read != -1 ? 1 : 0);
                return read;
            }

            @Override
            public int read(final byte[] b) throws IOException {
                final int read = old.read(b);
                readAndCheck(read != -1 ? read : 0);
                return read;
            }

            @Override
            public int read(final byte[] b, final int off, final int len) throws IOException {
                final int read = old.read(b, off, len);
                readAndCheck(read != -1 ? read : 0);
                return read;
            }

            @Override
            public long skip(final long n) throws IOException {
                final long skip = old.skip(n);
                readAndCheck(skip != -1 ? skip : 0);
                return skip;
            }

            @Override
            public int available() throws IOException {
                return old.available();
            }

            @Override
            public void close() throws IOException {
                old.close();
            }

            @Override
            public synchronized void mark(final int readlimit) {
                mark += readlimit;
                old.mark(readlimit);
            }

            @Override
            public synchronized void reset() throws IOException {
                this.length = 0;
                readAndCheck(mark);
                old.reset();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean markSupported() {
                return old.markSupported();
            }

            private void readAndCheck(final long read) {
                this.length += read;

                if (this.length > declared) {
                    throw new WebApplicationException(
                            Response.status(Response.Status.LENGTH_REQUIRED)
                                    .entity("No content-length provided.")
                                    .build());
                }
            }
        });

        final Object entity = context.proceed();

        context.setInputStream(old);

        return entity;
    }
}
```

In the interceptor above I am setting my own input stream that counts and checks number of bytes read from the original input stream. This implementation however also depends on how the underlying container processes the input stream (i.e. if it also checks content-length when reading input stream).

Comment: Man that is a perfect answer, that is **exactly** what I was trying to accomplish. Thank you!!